# How to fix expression not available error?

Tags: javascript, filter, scope

Here is the sample App.js:

```
//filtering student list based on keyup search value 
//array length is 0 if no match was found
search.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
   // Check to see if search term is empty or not
  if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
        const noResults = document.querySelector(".no-results");
         //how many student names matched the input
        console.log(studentListItems[0].children[0].children[1].textContent);
        const array = Array.from(studentListItems).filter(student => student.children[0].children[1].textContent.includes(e.target.value))
     //No names filtered
     //Every student item disappears, no-results li shows
        if (array.length == 0) {
                Array.from(studentListItems).forEach(student => {
                student.style.display = "none";
                });
                noResults.style.display = "block";
                replaceLinks(array)
            //show ones that match, hide ones that don't 
        } else if (array.length > 0) {
                    displayPage(array,1)
                    replaceLinks(array)
                    Array.from(studentListItems).forEach(item => {
                        if (item.children[0].children[1].textContent.includes(e.target.value)) {
                            item.style.display = "block";
                        } else {
                            item.style.display = "none";
                        }
                    })  
                    noResults.style.display = "none";
        }   
  } else {                  // Display the initial state if search term is empty
        displayPage(studentListItems, 1);
        replaceLinks(studentListItems);
    }

});
```

Here is a link to my JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6sa4702z/

When I type something into my search input, the console gives me 'script.js:155 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined' for the **filter function** that stores an array in the **variable** named **array**

As you can see though, when you console.log the studentListItems, you get output, so I don't why the filter function doesn't work?

I'm also getting an expression not available error, and I feel like that is related to that. Does this have to do with variable scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `console.log` is only testing the first element of your array. But when you run `filter`, there might be some other element in your array that is not what you expect and thus throwing an error.

Based on looking at your jsfiddle, you are injecting a new `.no-results` item at the end of your list. The important point here is that an `HTMLCollection` object is "live". This means that whenever the DOM gets updated, so does the data structure. So your `studentListItems` variable will update to contain this new element once it's added.

You can convert this `HTMLCollection` object to an array right away so this doesn't update or you can filter out any unwanted rows on the fly. Either option will solve your problem.

For more information about HTMLCollection see the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your jsfiddle, I think you have an extra element at the end of the studentListItems collection that doesn't contain the child elements you expect it to. Try this:

```
const array = Array.from(studentListItems).filter(student => student.children[0].children[1] && student.children[0].children[1].textContent.includes(e.target.value))
```

The result is that, if `student.children[0].children[1]` is null, the second part of the condition will not be evaluated and the exception you're seeing won't be thrown. I think you'd have to make this change in two places.